# Sort (symmetric) numpy 2D array by function. (norm)

Tags: arrays, sorting, numpy, norm

How to sort a matrix by the norm of its rows efficiently(using numpy.ndarrays)?

I want to sort the matrix A:

```
A = np.array( ( [ 10, 1, 6, 3 ],
                [  1,12, 2, 4 ],
                [  6, 2,14, 5 ],
                [  3, 4, 5, 9 ] ) )
```

by the norm of its rows.

What I do now is to create a list of the norm and get the indexlist of that list and sort the matrix based on that indexlist. Is this the way to go?

```
indexlist = np.argsort( np.apply_along_axis( np.linalg.norm, 0, A))
#indexlist = array([3, 0, 1, 2])
```

then my sorted list.

```
sortedA = A[indexlist]
```

and the symmetric sorted list would then be

```
sym_sortedA = A[indexlist][:,indexlist]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the most common way to do that. A bit shorter would be to use

```
indexlist = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(A,axis=1))
```

You need to use axis=1 if you want to sort by rows, but since the matrix is symmetric that doesn't matter.